# How can I use import and export with this simple code?

Tags: javascript, function, import, module, export

I want to use the doAlert function in the index.js file. Now, how do I use import and export in this situation?

```
//index.html
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>

//index.js
/*'index.js' is an empty file.*/

//doAlert.js
function doAlert() {
    alert('Hello');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* index.html */
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="doAlert.js"></script>

/* doAlert.js */
export function doAlert() {
    alert('Hello');
}

/* index.js */
import { doAlert } from './doAlert.js';
// use it
doAlert();
```

More info on JS modules: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: Yes. I tried it. But, it is not working. It was supposed to show an alert on the screen.But it doesn't.

Comment: Check this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-faraday-482yf?file=/src/index.js
It is working

Comment: the code is working in the link you provided. But it is not doing same in my code editor. I'm using VS Code. Is there something wrong with my editor? By the way, my index.html, index.js and doAlert.js files are in the same folder. The link you provided , there's another src folder.

Comment: Sorry, am I understand correctly, that you want to see `alert` in your text editor? It won't work because there is no any engine there to interpret and run your code.

Comment: If I do an alert on a single js file which is linked in the html file, it works perfectly. But, if I have two .js files and do a function that shows the alert is in one of them, it needs to be exported to another .js file which is connected to the html file. But using the import/export , it is not working. By the way, I know its not possible to show an alert in a code editor. I want it to show it in my browser window.

Comment: Can you try importing the doAlert file as well in index.html? Also it shouldn't matter where the js files are, as long as you provide the correct path. Are you using the Live Server extension on VSCode?

Comment: I also updated the import to include .js extension; please try again

Comment: Yes, I am using live server. It's awesome. Dont need to load everytime.

Comment: well, another problem occured. I was missing the .js extension in the import. But with the VS Code live server it shows the alert but without the live server, it doesn't. Why is that? I mean, they are still the same code.

Comment: For me it's working locally too now. Check this new link: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-morning-f7yz1?file=/index.html
It's doesn't have any bundler (webpack, parcel,..) so it should be the same as running with Live Server

Comment: If you just open the file with Chrome, it won't have the permission to run the included js files. Open the console on devtools and read the errors there, it gets blocked by CORS policy

Comment: This is clear to me now. Appreciate the help. Arigato...